Existence of parameter such that all real roots of a polynomial lie in any neighborhood of $l_1$

$l_1\in\mathbb{R}$. For all $ϵ>0$, there exist $x,y\in\mathbb R$ such that all real roots of the polynomial
$Q(l)=l^4 \left(y^2-3 x^2\right)+l^3 \left(-4 x^3+4 x^2+4 x y^2\right)+l^2 \left(14 x^4-28 x^3+12 x^2 y^2+14 x^2-12 x y^2-2 y^4-2 y^2\right)+l \left(-4 x^5+12 x^4-8 x^3 y^2-12 x^3+20 x^2 y^2+4 x^2-4 x y^4-12 x y^2+8 y^4\right)-3 x^6+12 x^5-9 x^4 y^2-18 x^4+24 x^3 y^2+12 x^3-9 x^2 y^4-20 x^2 y^2-3 x^2+12 x y^4+4 x y^2-3 y^6-2 y^4+y^2$
lie in the interval $[l_1-ϵ,l_1+ϵ]$.

The maximal constant $l_1$ such that the statement holds is the root $\approx32.0991$ of the polynomial $143 x^6-5346 x^5+25119 x^4-26712x^3-27000x^2+31104x+5616$.
How to prove this?

How about: Letting $x = 0$, all real roots of the quartic is $-1 \pm y\sqrt{3}$.

@RiverLi Thanks, now I know the minimal constant $l_1$ is $-1$, so I modified the question to find the maximal constant.

Yes, the maximal constant $l_1$ is that value. Once you reduce it to cubic, it is not difficult.

Substituting $y^2=3x^2$ into $Q(l)$,
$$Q(l)=l^3 (-2 x-1)+l^2 \left(-8 x^2+16 x-2\right)+l \left(16 x^3-36 x^2+12 x-1\right)+48 x^4-48 x^3+24 x^2-6 x$$
The discriminant of $Q(l)$ is
$$36 x^2 (2 x-1)^2 \left(832 x^6-11904 x^5+18816 x^4-13040 x^3+4704 x^2-744 x+13\right)$$
Substituting the root $x\approx 12.61$ into $Q(l)=0$, the largest real root is  the root $\approx32.0991$ of the polynomial $143 x^6-5346 x^5+25119 x^4-26712x^3-27000x^2+31104x+5616$ as required.
Solve[0==Q[l]/.x->Root[13-744#+4704#^2-13040#^3+18816#^4-11904#^5+832#^6&,4],l]

